# use SwipeView for a layout rather than images

Tags: android, layout

I'm using jason fry's SwipeView, he uses it for imageviews though, I'm struggling to replace it with a layout.

at the moment it works if I replace the ImageView with a TextView but how would I replace the Imageview with a layout
any help is appreciated thanks

package com.example;

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.R;
import uk.co.jasonfry.android.tools.ui.PageControl;
import uk.co.jasonfry.android.tools.ui.SwipeView;
import uk.co.jasonfry.android.tools.ui.SwipeView.OnPageChangedListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
SwipeView mSwipeView;

LinearLayout ll;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll = loadLayout();

    PageControl mPageControl = (PageControl) findViewById(R.id.page_control);
    mSwipeView = (SwipeView) findViewById(R.id.swipe_view);

    //loadImages();

    for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
    {
        mSwipeView.addView(new FrameLayout(this));
    }

    TextView i0 = new TextView(this);
    TextView i1 = new TextView(this);
    i0.setText("page 1");
    i1.setText("page 2");

    ((FrameLayout) mSwipeView.getChildContainer().getChildAt(0)).addView(ll);
    ((FrameLayout) mSwipeView.getChildContainer().getChildAt(1)).addView(ll);

    SwipeImageLoader mSwipeImageLoader = new SwipeImageLoader();

    mSwipeView.setOnPageChangedListener(mSwipeImageLoader);
    mSwipeView.setPageControl(mPageControl);
}

private class SwipeImageLoader implements OnPageChangedListener
{

    public void onPageChanged(int oldPage, int newPage)
    {
        if(newPage>oldPage)//going forwards
        {
            if(newPage != (mSwipeView.getPageCount()-1))//if at the end, don't load one page after the end
            {
                TextView v = new TextView(MyActivity.this);
                v.setText("page :"+(newPage+1));
                ((FrameLayout) mSwipeView.getChildContainer().getChildAt(newPage+1)).addView(ll);
            }
            if(oldPage!=0)//if at the beginning, don't destroy one before the beginning
            {
                ((FrameLayout) mSwipeView.getChildContainer().getChildAt(oldPage-1)).removeAllViews();
            }

        }
        else //going backwards
        {
            if(newPage!=0)//if at the beginning, don't load one before the beginning
            {

                TextView v = new TextView(MyActivity.this);
                v.setText("page :"+(newPage+1));
                ((FrameLayout) mSwipeView.getChildContainer().getChildAt(newPage-1)).addView(ll);
            }
            if(oldPage != (mSwipeView.getPageCount()-1))//if at the end, don't destroy one page after the end
            {
                ((FrameLayout) mSwipeView.getChildContainer().getChildAt(oldPage+1)).removeAllViews();
            }
        }

    }

}

private LinearLayout loadLayout()
{
    //logo
    ImageView logo = new ImageView(this);
    logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.image001);
    logo.setLayoutParams(new     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // espace
    TextView espace = new TextView(this);
    espace.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    espace.setText(" ");

    // wrap prest
    LinearLayout wprest = new LinearLayout(this);

    //Prestation
    TextView txt_pres = new TextView(this);
    txt_pres.setText("   Prestation n° ");
    txt_pres.setTextColor(R.color.black);
    // plaid
    TextView plaid = new TextView(this);
    plaid.setTextColor(R.color.black);
    plaid.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    plaid.setText("4558");
    // -
    TextView tiret = new TextView(this);
    tiret.setTextColor(R.color.black);
    tiret.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    tiret.setText(" - ");
    // plaid
    TextView platyp = new TextView(this);
    platyp.setTextColor(R.color.black);
    platyp.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    platyp.setText("ECHANGE");

    wprest.addView(txt_pres);
    wprest.addView(plaid);
    wprest.addView(tiret);
    wprest.addView(platyp);



    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

    ll.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new      LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    ll.addView(logo);
    ll.addView(espace);
    ll.addView(wprest);

    return ll;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try another ViewPager library, such as:

- android-viewflow (https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow)
- Android-ViewPagerIndicator (https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

because using it, you can easily custom children layout.

I see it's the most popular ViewPager libraries. For more detail, you can check out my "Android UI Patterns" app on Market: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns. There are many useful samples for developers.

Comment: thanks I only managed to find jason fry's example. great app by the way

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, and I'm finding it impossible to implement the ViewFlow

Comment: SwipeView exists because nothing else did at the time I originally created it. I've never compared the pros and cons of SwipeView with android-viewflow, the greendroid one, nor the official android one you can get in the compatibility pack, so I couldn't say which one is best :)

Comment: @fry15 I see what you mean. In fact each solution (SwipeView, android-viewflow...) has pros and cons. It's up developer to choose what's the best for them. For myself, in my first Anroid project at company, I use SwipeView because it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yo

I use this library all over the place for more than just images. I've used it with complex layouts, so it does work.

I've since added some new layout objects, but not documented them or created examples of how to use them (I'm a busy guy! :p ) One of them is called PageView, it uses an adapter, like a ListView, so if you know how to use a ListView you should be able to use this. The key is using the .setAdapter(BaseAdapter adapter) method.

Make sure you're using the latest one from github. Here's a link straight to the PageView class code on github: https://github.com/fry15/uk.co.jasonfry.android.tools/blob/master/src/uk/co/jasonfry/android/tools/widget/PageView.java